# Yesod devel won't reload static files

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am on Linux Mint 18.3 with Linux Kernel 4.13.0-26-generic.

I installed the scaffolded site using the instructions at https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart and I kept the vanilla dependencies.

When I use

```
$ stack exec -- yesod devel
```

if I update my Hamlet files, the change will not reflect on the website, even if I refresh with enter.

My Stack version is 1.9.1.

Please help.

Comment: Upvoted, same problem.

Comment: I experience the same issue from time to time, but with no apparent pattern.

Comment: Try touching the handler that references the Hamlet file. This usually solves it for me.